# Uploading Videos to VK with URL

Tags: php, api, video, vk

Is there any way to upload videos to vk servers directly from link

```
VkApi::factory()->method($access_token, 'video.save', array(
   'name' => "Example",
   'description' => "Nothing",
   'is_private' => false,
   'wallpost' => true,
   'link' => "http://example.com/video.mp4",
   "swfupload" => false
));
```

This returns;

> {"error_code":7,"error_msg":"no video found, check url"}

But in the real there is a video on the link. Any helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. this is not transfer videos from server A to vk server. It is a link for embedding videos. you can type a youtube video link to this fiels